# How can i split my mainwindow into 5 areas with QT-Layouts

Tags: qt, layout

I want to make a GUI with QT Creator 4.9.1 ,my aim is to split my mainwindow into 5 areas(no multiple window), my question is how can i realize that, or better what is the best Layout solution for that?

I have allready tried to set a datagrid and add inside that grid 5 frames, the problem is that the first frame has the size of my whole datagrid and i can't resize it.

My next try was to add 5 different datagrid on my GUI but i can't set the size of the datagrid's in QT like wpf or forms.

My last try and my current solution is without any layout, i add 5 fame's inside my mainwindow but that isn't a good solution.

[image]

Inside visual studio i realize that with datagrids i create for every menu one grid and change the visibility when the user need a other (area 2).

friendly wishes sniffi

Comment: For it I would suggest using dock windows.

Comment: For what was the downrating? what have i done wrong?

Comment: Use q splitter
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion to using dock windows may be a good one to investigate, particularly if you need to allow the user to resize or move things around. However, to get the layout you want with just layouts, the trick is to use multiple layouts.

Create a vertical layout for the left-hand side and add the four widgets to it. Create a horizontal layout and add the vertical layout in the first column and your tall, fifth widget to the second column. Apply the layout to your main windows, and that should give you roughly what you're looking for.

You'll almost certainly need to play with the row stretches on the vertical layout to get the proportions you want, and with the column stretches on the horizontal layout.

The alternate would be to create a grid layout where the widget on the right side spans four rows, but I think you'll be happier with the mix of the two layouts.

Comment: Can i resize my items inside the Layout with code, or is the only way to change the size with the Stretch and Margin?

Comment: The layout will respect the size hints on your widgets within the layout cells, but what I typically find that I want is most of the rows in a vertical layout to stay constant with one row accepting all of the extra space. It may be that you want a couple of rows to split the space equally. It just depends on your needs. I've just found that I have to experiment a lot to get the effects I want.

Comment: I have did it like you wrote it and it work fine thanks.